# Positioning a Fieldset CSS

Tags: css, fieldset

I'm trying to center a group of fieldsets that I have, every example I find online tells me to use margin: auto; but that doesn't seem to be working for me. I've also tried grouping them into a div but that didn't work either.

Here is my CSS:

```css
fieldset {
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto;
    display: inline;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I doubt you want an inline fieldset. Probably, you want `display: inline-block`

Comment: `inline-block` element won't respond to `margin:auto`. It only initializes default block behavior for the browser (proper top&bottom margin and padding) but the `margin:auto` :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `margin:auto` when element is `display:inline`.

You should either make them `display:block` to repond to `margin:auto` or style their wrap element to `text-align:center` and then reset `text-align` in descendants.

Comment: Thank you. First time using the display element.